# Unable to remove area MVC4 Internet application

Tags: html, css

In the screenshot below i have selected a area with firebug.
This is the standard mvc4 internet application template.

As you can see the area above the selected area consist of:

- Header
- Body
- Footer

I am unable to remove the highlighted area (under the footer).
How can i remove this so the footer is actually at the bottom?

Could also someone explain what this area exactly is? I got me completely puzzled.

[image]

Regards P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area below the footer is just... empty space.  HTML elements stack top down.

If you want a fixed footer on the bottom, apply a style like this:

```
footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
}​
```